# Container in one pod communicating with one in a multicontainer pod

Tags: docker, kubernetes, containers

- I am trying to figure out the networking in Kubernetes, and especially the handling of multicontainer pods. In my simple scenario, I have total of 3 pods. One has two containers in it and the other one has only one container which wants to communicate with a specific container in that multicontainer pod. I want to figure out how kubernetes handles the communication between such containers.

  For this purpose I have simple multicontainer pod in a "sidecar architecture" the YAML file is as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  containers:
 - name: nginx-container
    image: nginx
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
 - name: sidecar
    image: curlimages/curl
    command: ["/bin/sh"]
    args: ["-c", "echo Hello from the sidecar container; sleep 300"]
    ports:
    - containerPort: 5000
```

- What I want to achieve with this YAML file is that, in the pod "nginx", have two containers, one running nginx and listens on the port 80 of that pod the other running a simple curl image (anything different than nginx to not violate one container per pod convention of kubernetes) and can listen communication on pod's port 5000.

  Then I have another YAML file again running an nginx image. This container is going to trying to communicate with the nginx and curl images on the other pod. The YAML file is as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: nginx-simple
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  containers:
 - name: nginx-container
    image: nginx
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
```

- After deploying the pods I expose the nginx pod simply using the following command:

  `kubectl expose pods/nginx`
- Then I start a terminal inside the nginx-simple container.(Pod with one container). When I curl the ip address I get from `kubectl get svc` which is the service generated from my previous expose command with port 80, I can easily get the welcome message of nginx. However, the problem starts when I try to communicate with the curl container. When I curl the same ip adrress but this time with port 5000(containerPort I set in the Yaml file), I get a connection refused error. What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance.

P.S: I would also be more than happy to hear your learning material suggestions for this topic. Thank you so much.

Comment: Just because you declared a port in the yaml doesn't mean that you have a container listening to that port. Your application running in that container is a curl, it is not listening to any ports.

Comment: I see but shouldnt i be able to ping this curl container? I am trying to figure out how a container in one pod can communicate with a specific container in another pod which is a multicontainer one. Thanks.

Comment: No, once the curl command terminates, the container dies. You need a server process in that container

Comment: You don't communicate with containers, you communicate with pods. Containers in a pod share the same network space, so containers in a pod can communicate among themselves via 'localhost', and the pod itself is accessible using either a service, or by directly using the pod IP. To a process outside the pod, the containers making up the pod are invisible. If multiple containers should be accessed outside, you expose them on different pods. They are like processes running on a host.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[curl](https://curl.se/) is a command line tool. It is not a server that is listening to a port, but a client tool that can be used to access servers.

This container does not contain a *server* that listen to a port:

```
 - name: sidecar
   image: curlimages/curl
   command: ["/bin/sh"]
   args: ["-c", "echo Hello from the sidecar container; sleep 300"]
   ports:
   - containerPort: 5000
```

Services deployed on Kubernetes are typically containers containing some form of webserver, but might be other kind of services as well.

---

> shouldnt i at least be able to ping the curl container?

Nope, containers are not Virtual Machines. Containers typically only contain a single **process** and a container can only do what that process do. On Kubernetes these processes are typically webservers listening e.g. on port 8080, so commonly you can only check if they are alive by sending them an HTTP-request. See e.g. [Configure Liveness, Readiness and Startup Probes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-liveness-readiness-startup-probes/).

> When i run telnet pod-ip 5000 i cannot ping this curl container.

The [curl](https://curl.se/) binary is not a process that listen to any port. E.g. it cannot respond to [ICMP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Control_Message_Protocol). You can typically ping nodes but not containers. Curl is a http-client that typically is used to **send and http-request, wait for the http-response and then the process terminates. You can probably see this by inspecting the Pod, that the curl container has terminated.

> I am trying to figure out how communication is handled in a multicontainer pod. Each pod has their own unique ip address and containers in the pod can use localhost. I get it but how a container in a different pod can target a specific container in a multicontainer pod?

I suggest that you add **two** webservers (e.g. two nginx containers) to a pod. But they have to listen to different ports, e.g. port 8080 and port 8081. A client can choose what container it want to interact with by using the Pod IP and the container Port, `<Pod IP>:<containerPort>`. E.g. add two nginx-containers, configure them to listen to different ports and let them serve different content.

Comment: First of all thank you for your time and for your answer. Hmm... i see. Actually i figured it out but shouldnt i at least be able to ping the curl container? When i run telnet pod-ip 5000 i cannot ping this curl container. I am trying to figure out how communication is handled in a multicontainer pod. Each pod has their own unique ip address and containers in the pod can use localhost. I get it but how a container in a different pod can target a specific container in a multicontainer pod?

Comment: I have updated my answer to respond to the questions.

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer Jonas. So in short, it is our responsibility to make containers in a multicontainer pod listen different ports and the other container in a different pod what wants to communicate should be aware of the port number of the container it wants to speaks to? Is this correct?

Comment: Other pods should not need to be aware of the ports of specific containers. You typically use the default port for a protocol, e.g. port 80 for http, and you create a Service for each app, this service can map port 80 to e.g. targetPort 8081 and the Other Pod should only access the Service. See e.g. https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/

Comment: Now everything is crystal clear. Thank you so much for your time and for your help Jonas. Kind regards.